# High resolution to low resolution

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have an image of lets say 256x256. I want to reduce the resolution of that and wants to keep the size of the image same. I want to try this method for 30 and 60 band image.
I found this code

```
I=im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
 N=size(I);
 for x=1:N(1)-6
    for y=1:N(2)-6
        Sample=I(x:x+6,y:y+6);
        Lores(x,y)=mean(Sample(:));   
    end
 end
 figure,imshow(I), title(' Original');
 figure, imshow(Lores), title(' Low resolution')
```

Which averages 6 pixels to 1 . Is there any other or better way to do?

Comment: lol.. which one you can do?

Answer (score 2):

That about using an [N-D convolution](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html) to blur the image?

```
img = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
conv_mat = ones(6) / 36;
img_low = convn(img,conv_mat,'same');

figure, imshow(img), title('Original');
figure, imshow(img_low), title('Low Resolution')
```

Comment: conv_mat = ones(6) / 36
that 6 and 36 means how many pixels to be averaged? for example if i want to do with 16 pixels then it will be conv_mat = ones(16) / 256?

Comment: Yes. For example `ones(2)/4` will be a `2-by-2` pixel averaging.

Comment: Yes. Can you please tell me how can write that in mathematical form?

Comment: Bluring and making low resolution image is same?